# wp_get_recent_posts( $args ) returning empty array

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

```
<?php $args = array(
                'numberposts' => 3,
                'offset' => 0,
                'orderby' => 'post_date',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'include' => '',
                'exclude' => '',
                'meta_key' =>'_thumbnail_id' ,
                'meta_value' => '',
                'post_type' => 'Topics',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'suppress_filters' => true );
                $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args);
                echo '<pre>';print_r($recent_posts); ?>
```

The `wp_get_recent_posts( $args )` is returning an empty array, although I do have a post type with name "topics" and it does contain a few posts in it. Any idea why is that happening?

Comment: Are the posts you have loaded published?

Comment: Yes. All the parameters that you are seeing in the code above are valid.

Comment: Is your post_type a registered custom post_type? According to https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types, 'Topics', is not a valid default.

Comment: Yes! When I am using `<?php $post_types = get_post_types(); 
   echo '<pre>';print_r($post_types);?>` to view the registered post names, it does return "topics" as one of the registered post.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. I'm not sure how strict WP is, but try making 'Topics' all lowercase, 'topics'.

Comment: When we register a custom post type even with uppercase letters, it does convert it to lower case before registering it. All the registered post types it  is returning are lowercase. However, I have tried it your way too but no use.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. Removing `'meta_key' =>'_thumbnail_id' ,` is returning the right array as expected. It's because probably there is no thumbnail for those posts.